# Not beginning with vowels and not ending with vowels

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm practicing a challenge on Hackerrank where the question is return list of all cities from a Table 'STATION' where the cities do not begin with vowels and do not end with vowels.

This query doesn't work:

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where CITY NOT LIKE '[A,E,I,O,U]% 
[a,e,i,o,u]'
```

But this query does work:

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where CITY NOT LIKE '[A,E,I,O,U]%' 
AND CITY NOT LIKE '%[a,e,i,o,u]'
```

Could anyone please help me understand why the first query is not working?

Comment: neither of your queries actually work. you should refer to the documentation for the correct syntax. there is no comma delimiter

Comment: The first query looks for cities that don't start *and* end in a vowel. Seattle and Austin are fine, Atlanta isn't. The second looks for those that don't start *or* end in a vowel. Seattle, Austin, and Atlanta all fail there. Also, you don't need the commas in the pattern: `[AEIOU]` matches any of those characters.

Answer (score 4):

Your second query sort of works -- because commas are not going to appear at the beginning or end of the name.

In all likelihood. the desired solution is a single pattern:

```
where city like '[^aeiou]%[^aeiou]'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select distinct city
from station
where city rlike '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*' and city rlike '^.*[^aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Comment: `^.*` is not required in the latter regex, `[^aeiouAEIOU]$` will anyways match any string not ending with vowels.

Comment: SQL Server (as question is tagged) does not have a `rlike` operator

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT CITY  FROM STATION  WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(CITY, 1, 1)) NOT IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')
     AND UPPER(SUBSTR(C.CITY, LENGTH(CITY), 1)) NOT IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with MySQL solution :

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where substr(CITY, 1, 1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u') and substr(CITY, -1, 1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Station WHERE City NOT LIKE '%A' AND City NOT LIKE '%E' AND City NOT LIKE '%I' AND City NOT LIKE '%O' AND City NOT LIKE '%U' AND City NOT LIKE 'A%' AND City NOT LIKE 'E%' AND City NOT LIKE 'I%' AND City NOT LIKE 'O%' AND City NOT LIKE 'U%' ORDER BY City
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE (CITY NOT LIKE 'A%'
    AND CITY  NOT LIKE 'E%'
    AND CITY NOT LIKE 'I%' 
    AND CITY NOT LIKE 'O%'
    AND CITY NOT LIKE 'U%')
        AND (CITY NOT LIKE '%a' AND
            CITY  NOT LIKE '%e' AND
            CITY NOT LIKE '%i' AND 
            CITY NOT LIKE '%o' AND 
            CITY NOT LIKE '%u');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE LOWER(RIGHT(CITY,1)) NOT IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') AND 
      LOWER(LEFT(CITY,1)) NOT IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please edit an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

give a try on below code

```
select distinct city from station
where left(city,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u')
and right(city,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use basic `LIKE` statements to select the first letter.
Here, I have used `NOT LIKE` to exclude vowels.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE LOWER(city) NOT LIKE 'a%'
AND LOWER(city) NOT LIKE 'e%'
AND LOWER(city) NOT LIKE 'i%'
AND LOWER(city) NOT LIKE 'o%'
AND LOWER(city) NOT LIKE 'u%';
```